# Overlapping event areas

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, event-handling

I got a square component inside a canvas which when clicked shows a glow effect-indicating selection-while clicking somewhere else this effect is removed-indicating deselection
The problem is that the canvas always dispatches the "deselect" event, even if the mouse if over the square.
I worked around this by defining a circumstantial function which removes the child's width,height from the parent's "clickable" area.

Is there a better way to tell the canvas to dispatch his event only if not over the child ?

[Explanatory image](http://img208.imageshack.us/i/bild000.png)

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without any code, but my guess is, you should stop propagation of the click event in the listener for the square component: `event.stopPropagation();`
That way, the stage will not be notified of the click on the square and may not send your "deselect" event.